# Scoping of OptionValue for inner functions in closures

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, optional-arguments

Assume a function `f` is a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) over an inner function `g`. Both `f` and `g` have `Options` attached to them. Can then `g`, defined inside `f` use the options of `f` via `OptionValue`? In the following (somewhat silly) example `buildCar` corresponds to `f` and `addSeats` corresponds to `g`). If the options of `f` were not options but arguments the case would be simple.

**Example using arguments for the outer function**

```
buildCar[color_] := Module[{addSeats},
(* imagine a slow assembly line that builds most of the car, 
except the seats *)

Options[addSeats] = {"Seats" -> "Leather"};
addSeats[OptionsPattern[]] := {color, OptionValue["Seats"]};

(* return a function that lets you add seats to the car *)
addSeats
]
```

This works then as follows:

```
preFab = buildCar[Blue]
(* returns the inner function addSeats$138697 *)

myCar = preFab["Seats" -> "Cloth"]
(* {Blue, "Cloth"} *)
```

Notice that changing the color of the car is not possible after `preFab` is instantiated and only the type of seats may be changed.

---

Compare this to the case where `color` is not an argument but an option.

**Working example**

```
ClearAll@buildCar

Options[buildCar] = {"Color" -> Red};
buildCar[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{color, addSeats},

color = OptionValue["Color"]; (* <-- notice this "unpacking of the color option"*)
Options[addSeats] = {"Seats" -> "Leather"};
addSeats[OptionsPattern[]] := {color, OptionValue["Seats"]};
addSeats
]
```

]

Notice that just using `OptionValue["Color"]` in the r.h.s. definition of `addSeats` does not work (see non-working example below) and one has to *unpack* the option (by assigning it to the local symbol `color`). My actual question boiled down to this example is then: Can one avoid unpacking the `Options` of `buildCar` (imagine there were a lot of them) without some crude hack? Is there a way to provide `OptionValue` with the scope it should look at?

---

**Non-working example**

```
ClearAll@buildCar

Options[buildCar] = {"Color" -> Red};
buildCar[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{color, addSeats},

Options[addSeats] = {"Seats" -> "Leather"};
addSeats[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[buildCar, "Color"], OptionValue["Seats"]};

addSeats
]

preFab = buildCar["Color" -> Blue];
myCar = preFab["Seats" -> "Cloth"]
(* {Red, "Cloth"} *)
```

Comment: Does something like this work? `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/vytiK.png"]`